# How to extract the specific value from a json object in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have json output from my set variable activity as
{
"name": "value",
"value": "123456"
}

I want only the "123456" as output for my next activity. And if possible in the integer format.
Any suggestions and thoughts would be valuable.
Thanks

I tried extracting the value but it being in string format gave me the error.

Answer (score 0):

In a Set variable activity you can do this assuming var1 contains the json { "name": "value", "value": "123456" }

```
@json(variables('var1')).value
```

There is no integer data type for variables so the output of the Set variable will look like below but the value is really just 123456.  You can use the int() function to convert it to a number where you are using it.

```
{
    "name": "var2",
    "value": "123456"
}
```